# Materials based on quantum tunneling: conductivity

Tags: electrical-resistance, material-science, conductors, quantum-tunneling

Suppose you have a nanocomposite wire in which electrons can move through it exclusively with the electron tunneling between conductive nanoparticles that are within optimal distance (like in figure below jumping from a conductive nanoparticle to another).
Can a macroscopic wire like that be used to conduct electricity efficiently? What are the main differences in conductivity properties compared to a regular copper wire?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean that the distances, the tunneling probabilities or the sizes of different grains are not the same, so that we are dealing here with *granular disordered system* (as opposed to periodical identical grains/atoms, which would be described by a Bloch theorem - which can be also artificially created).

There are several different directions that one could explore:

- **Physics of granular systems**: one could start with [this old review](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.79.469) and follow the articles citing it in application to one-dimensional systems. There are indeed different transport regimes, depending on the parameters of the system (size and the conductivity of the grains, their density, etc.)
- **Anderson localization** is less about granules and more about how disorder may affect transport in 1D system - specifically, it becomes non-conducting.
- More generally: *disordered systems, weaks/strong localization* - the subject has been studied extensively, although not necessarily in the context of granules, but semiconductors filled with randomly dispersed impurities. Still, many the physical features are the same.
- Another generalization: **one-dimensional structures**, which lead in directions like **Landauer-Büttiker formalism** for no electron-electron interactions and **Luttinger liquids** when the interactions are important.
- Finally, **tunneling in disordered semiconductors** is an important subject in itself - I could suggest [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17943125/).